# Space Invaders ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, 2d-games

Okey, I've searched for this error and found out that the cause is probably that my update of the Arraylist is somehow conflicting with my repaint() method. I have changed my code many times trying to fix it but either I can't compile or I end up with the exact same error.
I am creating Space Invaders and the game runs fine until I shoot to fast (ie. tap the UP button to fast) and this error comes up:
(NB:the x in "Index: x, Size: x" is not always 1 it has ranged from 1 to 6)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at Board.checkCollisions(Board.java:185)
at Board.actionPerformed(Board.java:172)
at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:312)
at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:244)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here is the part of the code that seems to cause the problem.

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(enemies.size() == 0){
        ingame = false;
    }

    ArrayList ss = gun.getShots();

    for(int i = 0; i < ss.size(); i++){
        Shot s = (Shot) ss.get(i);
        if(s.isVisible()){
            s.move();
        }
        else{
            ss.remove(i);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++){
        Enemy en = (Enemy) enemies.get(i);
        if(en.isVisible()){
            en.move();
        }
        else{
            enemies.remove(i);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < bunkers.size(); i++){
        Bunker b = (Bunker) bunkers.get(i);
        if(b.isVisible() == false){
            bunkers.remove(i);
        }
    }

    gun.move();
    checkCollisions();
    repaint();
}

public void checkCollisions(){

    ArrayList ss = gun.getShots();

    for(int i = 0; i < ss.size(); i++){
        Shot s = (Shot) ss.get(i);
        Rectangle r1 = s.getBounds();
        //Collision for Enemies
        for(int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++){
            Enemy en = (Enemy) enemies.get(i);
            Rectangle r2 = en.getBounds();

            if(r1.intersects(r2)){
                s.setVisible(false);
                en.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
        //Collision for Bunker
        for(int j = 0; j < bunkers.size(); j++){
            Bunker b = (Bunker) bunkers.get(i);
            Rectangle r2 = b.getBounds();

            if(r1.intersects(r2)){
                s.setVisible(false);
                b.setVisible(false);
                score++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

More specifically these lines of code:

```
checkCollisions();
Enemy en = (Enemy) enemies.get(i);
```

and sometimes

```
checkCollisions();
Bunker b = (Bunker) bunkers.get(i);
```

Also there is another problem. For some reason when I shoot the aliens or when I shoot at the bunker I always have to shoot the one that is first in the ArrayList for it too disappear. If I shoot the others first nothing happens, the shot just flies through them. This is not my primary concern so I understand if you do not want to waste time explaining that to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that you are mutating the `List` from two different threads...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that these two snippets are the problem:

```
    for(int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++){
        Enemy en = (Enemy) enemies.get(i);


    for(int j = 0; j < bunkers.size(); j++){
        Bunker b = (Bunker) bunkers.get(i);
```

You iterate with `j`, but you use `i` in the getter.

Comment: The fact that you caught the deserves a +1, that fact that you might have actually found the problem means it's well deserved ;)

Comment: WOW how in the hell could I not have seen that! This fixed both errors, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

> Here is the part of the code that seems to cause the problem.

There's no need to guess as the exception stacktrace should tell you **exactly** which line causes the exception. If you post a similar problem, you will want to indicate to us which line is causing the problem, here it is `at Board.checkCollisions(Board.java:185)`, or line 185 of Board.java.

This code looks suspicious:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bunkers.size(); i++){
    Bunker b = (Bunker) bunkers.get(i);
    if(b.isVisible() == false){
        bunkers.remove(i);
    }
}
```

You're removing an item from a list while iterating forward through it -- something you should  not do since it will often cause an AIOOBE like you're seeing. Consider iterating *backwards* through the collection.